# How to use timerfd properly?

Tags: c, linux, timer, zeromq

I use `timerfd` with zmq.

How can I use `timerfd_create` and `timerfd_set` to wait one second for the timer (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html)?

I have looked through the link but I still do not get how I can initilize a timer that waits one second per tick with create and set. This is exactly my task:

> We start a timer with `timerfd_create()`, which is 1 / sec. ticking. When setting a timer with timer`_set_(..)` a
> counter is simply incremented, which is decremented with every tick. When the counter reaches 0, the timer
> has expired.

In this project we have a function timer `_ set _()`, where the timer is set with the function timerfd_create and `timerfd_settimer()`. I hope you can help me.

This is my progress (part of my code):

```
    struct itimerspec timerValue;

    g_items[n].socket = nullptr; 
    g_items[n].events = ZMQ_POLLIN;

    g_items[n].fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    if(g_items[n].fd == -1 ){
        printf("timerfd_create() failed: errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }  

    timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timerValue.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    timerfd_settime(g_items[n].fd,  0, &timerValue, NULL);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question appears about setting correctly the timeouts of the timer.

With the settings

```
timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
timerValue.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
timerValue.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
```

You are correctly setting the *initial timeout* to 1s (field `timerValue.it_value`). But you are also setting a *periodic interval* of 1s, and you didn't mention the will to do it.

---

### About the timeouts

This behavior is described by the following passage of the manual:

> `int timerfd_create(int clockid, int flags);`
> **`new_value.it_value`** specifies the initial expiration of the timer, in seconds and nanoseconds.  Setting either field of `new_value.it_value` to a nonzero value arms the timer.
> Setting both fields of `new_value.it_value` to zero disarms the timer.
> Setting one or both fields of `new_value.it_interval` to nonzero values specifies the period, in seconds and nanoseconds, for repeated timer expirations after the initial expiration. **If both fields of `new_value.it_interval` are zero, the timer expires just once, at the time specified by `new_value.it_value`.**

The emphasis on the last paragraph is mine, as it shows what to do in order to have a single-shot timer.

---

### The benefits of `timerrfd`. How to detect timer expiration?

The main advantage provided by `timerfd` is that the timer is associated to a file descriptor, and this means that it

> may be monitored by [`select`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select), [`poll`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), and [`epoll`(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll).

The information contained in the other answer about `read()` is valid as well: let's just say that, even using functions such as `select()`, `read()` function will be required in order to consume data in the file descriptor.

---

### A complete example

In the following demonstrative program, a timeout of 4 seconds is set; after that a periodic interval of 5 seconds is set.

The good old `select()` is used in order to wait for timer expiration, and `read()` is used to consume data (that is the number of expired timeouts; we will ignore it).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,  0);
    
    printf("Starting at (%d)...\n", (int)time(NULL));
    
    if(tfd > 0)
    {
        char dummybuf[8];
        struct itimerspec spec =
        {
            { 5, 0 }, // Set to {0, 0} if you need a one-shot timer
            { 4, 0 }
        };
        timerfd_settime(tfd, 0, &spec, NULL);

        /* Wait */
        fd_set rfds;
        int retval;

        /* Watch timefd file descriptor */
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(0, &rfds);
        FD_SET(tfd, &rfds);

        /* Let's wait for initial timer expiration */
        retval = select(tfd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL); /* Last parameter = NULL --> wait forever */
        printf("Expired at %d! (%d) (%d)\n", (int)time(NULL), retval, read(tfd, dummybuf, 8) );
        
        /* Let's wait (twice) for periodic timer expiration */
        retval = select(tfd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Expired at %d! (%d) (%d)\n", (int)time(NULL), retval, read(tfd, dummybuf, 8) );

        retval = select(tfd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        printf("Expired at %d! (%d) (%d)\n", (int)time(NULL), retval, read(tfd, dummybuf, 8) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here it is the output. Every row contains also the timestamp, so that the actual elapsed time can be checked:

```
Starting at (1596547762)...
Expired at 1596547766! (1) (8)
Expired at 1596547771! (1) (8)
Expired at 1596547776! (1) (8)
```

Please note:

- We just performed 3 reads, for test
- The intervals are 4s + 5s + 5s (initial timeout + two interval timeouts)
- 8 bytes are returned by `read()`. We ignored them, but they contained the number of the expired timeouts

Comment: Why do you do tfd+1 in select? And the time of initial timeout is just for the first run, and after that the timer takes the time of the interval timeouts?

Comment: @zongul67 You can pass to `select` more than one descriptor. By design that parameter must contain the max fd + 1 (in this case `tfd+1`. Talking about the timeouts, your guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

With timerfds, the idea is that a **read** on the fd will return the number of times the timer has expired.

From the **timerfd_settime(2)** man page:

> Operating on a timer file descriptor
> The file descriptor returned by timerfd_create() supports the following operations:
>
> read(2)
> If  the  timer  has  already expired one or more times since its settings were last modified using
> timerfd_settime(), or since the last successful read(2), then the buffer given to read(2)  returns
> an  unsigned  8-byte  integer  (uint64_t) containing the number of expirations that have occurred.

> If  no  timer  expirations  have  occurred at the time of the read(2), then the call either blocks
> until the next timer expiration, or fails with the error EAGAIN if the file  descriptor  has  been
> made nonblocking (via the use of the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to set the O_NONBLOCK flag).

So, basically, you create an unsigned 8 byte integer (uint64_t on Linux), and pass that to your read call.

```
uint64_t buf;
int expired = read( g_items[n].fd, &buf, sizeof(uint64_t));
if( expired < 0 ) perror("read");
```

Something like that, if you want to block until you get an expiry.