# C++ killing child thread stops execution of the main thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I am completely confused with timers and how threads (pthread) work in C++

Timers arent timers but clocks and you cant (I at least cant) kill a thread without killing main thread.

What I need - a bit of code which executes once in 24hrs on a separate thread.

However if the app needs to stop it - I cant do anything but send SIGKILL to it (because join will wait till midnight). Once I kill that thread the app (main thread) seems to kill itself also.

I am open to suggestions.

On condition - *I **cannot** use std::threads and I dont want to wake this thread more than once a day*

But easiest for me would be to kill a child thread without stopping execution of the main thread (why this is the case anyway??)

Here is the sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

void* Logger(void* arg) {

    int* thread_state = (int*)arg;

    cout << "Logger started" << endl;

    sleep(24 * 60 * 60);

    cout << "Logger thread exiting" << endl;

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int thread_state = 0;
    pthread_t logger_t;

    int rc = pthread_create(&logger_t, NULL, Logger, (void*)&thread_state);

    sleep(2);

    //thread_state = 1;
    pthread_kill(logger_t, SIGKILL);

    cout << "i wuz here" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Logger started
Killed
```

Comment: You send a message to the thread and ask it politely to stop. If the thread is written correctly it will receive the message and politely stop. The message could be as simple as setting an atomic boolean flag. The big thing here is don't sleep for great long periods of time unless you have an interruptible sleep. Consider instead sleeping for a second, checking to see if the thread has been asked to exit, and then either looping back around and sleeping again or exiting.

Comment: A brute force exit of a thread, killing the thread for example, will often result in an unstable program because it's really hard to predict exactly what the thread is doing when it's terminated. Your code might be able to handle it, but what about all the stuff around your code or called by your code?

Comment: to examine the flag i need to wake up. and as i said - i dont want to wake it up. or else i wont be asking. thank you for understanding.

Comment: `timerfd` along with `select` or `epoll` can make POSIX timers much easier to use in Linux. [Here's a quick example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63248074/4581301)

Comment: Wait on any synchro object with a 24-hr timeout.  If the wait times out, perform your scheduled operation.  If it is signaled, clean up and exit.  You can then signal the thread to instrict it to exit.  No polling required.

Comment: @MartinJames write a sample and I mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how I missed it but if I call `pthread_cancel` instead of `pthread_kill` it works just fine.

Comment: Oh, just seen this.  Even better :)

Comment: Better than kill, but you still have to be careful with it in the general case. Use `pthread_setcancelstate` to ensure you don't cancel while holding a mutex, for example.

Comment: yes thank you. all is taken care now. i kill the thread in question before the app termination. I just needed to have clean exit and ensure destructors to be ran properly - and if I use KILL the destructors are not called. that was my main issue. now is OK